# How to fix "load unsafe scripts"?

Tags: github, github-pages

so I'll start from the very beginning.

Basicly I purchased a template off themeforest and I manually edited the code in a markup editor to match my preferences.

As I was finished, I decided to host my website on github pages - I uploaded my code directory to a repository as you do.

Here's a link to my repository:
https://github.com/KristofferHari/kristofferhari.github.io

Here's a link to my current website URL:
https://kristofferhari.github.io/ (As you can see, everything's kinda buggy)

---

So I managed to contact the seller and this is what I was provided with:

> ***The reason for that is because the resources are using a http connection and they can’t be loaded on https connection website. So
>   you have to upload all the resources (scripts/stylesheets) to github
>   in order to use them on github.***

So I suppose that through my browser, I am trying to connect to my website through a https connection rather than an http. *(Is this what is actually causing the problem, and what's the difference between a http connection and a https?)*

Secondly, how would I upload all my resources (scripts/stylesheets) to github?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: s stands for secure you will need to change your links to assets to https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a relatively simple solution: to use a protocol-relative URL format.

e.g. your error

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://kristofferhari.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,900'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The problem is you are loading

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,900'
```

from

```
https://kristofferhari.github.io/
```

The page is secure (HTTPS), but it's loading insecure content (HTTP).

To fix it, you basically need to change the stylesheet to:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,900'
```

But a more flexible solution is to use a protocol relative format:

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,900'
```

which will then work on either http or https.

Apply this change to all included resources.

Comment: Thanks alot scipilot! That explained it. Your help was much appreciated!